# Recursive SELECT query in Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I got two following tables

category:(one to many-----question)

```
id name  parentId
1  test1  0
2  test2  1
3  test3  1
4  test4  3 .....
```

like a tree

```
test1
  test2
  test3
    test4
```

question:

```
id   title      category_id
1   question1    1
2   ....         1
3   ....         2
```

my question is : if i search category id = 1 ,there will be print total questions:

```
count(question.id)
     3
```

How to build Select query to do that? is that possible?

Thank you for your valuable help.

Comment: Why do You think it should be `Recursive SELECT` ?

Comment: @oleg  why not? give me some tips..

Comment: simple select with `COUNT` and `WHERE` as @Legionar has proposed or `COUNT` with `GROUP BY` if You need more questions count not for `category_id=1` only

Comment: no,You do not understand my intentions,the category table like a tree..

Comment: Unlike almost all other DBMS MySQL does not support recursive queries. You will need to write a stored procedure for that (or upgrade e.g. to Postgres or Firebird)

Comment: ...or join the table to itself as often as could ever be required, or switch to an alternative model (nested set), or handle the logic at the application level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return count of questions for your selected category, here in example `category_id = 1`:

```
mysqli_query('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM question WHERE category_id = 1');
```

**Updated:**
so, if you want to count it also for subcategories, the simpliest way will be to have "path" in your `category` table, where will be all IDs (self ID and ID-s of all parents), and you can separate it with `~` (its important to have `~` also at the beginning and end of path; path can be `VARCHAR(255)`, but if you want have really deep tree, you can use `TEXT`.

```
id name   parentId  path
1  test1  0         ~1~
2  test2  1         ~1~2~
3  test3  1         ~1~3~
4  test4  3         ~1~3~4~
```

Hope, its clear enough, how you will update your table `category` to have there also column `path`.

And the select then will be:

```
mysqli_query('
  SELECT COUNT(id)
  FROM question
  WHERE category_id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM category
    WHERE path LIKE "%~'.$category_id.'~%"
  )
');
```

`$category_id` will be ID of category, for which you want to count questions (also for subcategories).

Comment: how to get the questions belong category's subcategories?

Comment: Then you should use recursive query; sorry, it was not clear enough in your question.

Comment: It is my fault, i did not describe the problem clearly. But also thank you for your answer.

Comment: I can help, how deep will be your category tree? It will be exact number, or you dont know how deep it will be?

Comment: i dont know how deep it will be, if you can help me, Whatever you do will be great.

Comment: See my updated answer. Ask, if something is not clear. It will work.

Comment: nice catch,Thank you very much, i will try to follow your idea.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very simple query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM question WHERE category_id='1';
```

But you probably want a join query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM question INNER JOIN category 
ON (question.category_id = category.id) WHERE category.name='test1';
```

That will give you the option of searching for category names.

(BTW, did you google this?)

Edit: took me a cup of coffee, but indeed a `LEFT JOIN` does not make sense if the `WHERE` is on the joined table. `INNER JOIN` does.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, hum, Perhaps I did not describe the problem clearly. a category may be has subcategories, and i want get all the questions even that question belongs subcategories

Comment: There really isn't much point combining a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` with a `WHERE` condition on the joined table - unless that `WHERE` condition is `IS NULL`

Comment: Leo, my guess was that you want to get the questions that belong to a category. My second query allows searching for category name and get the number of questions.

Comment: Strawberry, enlighten me: how would you search for questions based on category name?

Comment: See a_horse_with_no_name's (and my) comment above. Your answer still misses the point. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Try like this,

```
 SELECT COUNT(id) FROM question WHERE category_id IN (SELECT id FROM question WHERE category_id='1')
```

Comment: This does NOT do anything that makes sense. The subquery is not necessary if you already know the category_id.

Comment: That select is completly wrong, you are mixing question_id with category_id. Just read it once again, and you will see that its wrong...